# Python Queue and Threading confusion

Tags: python, multithreading

I made a sniffer in Python which calculates the size of IP packets. I tried to get the size in two ways:

1) simply by calculating len(pkt)

2) by extracting the packet length from the IP header and adding 14bytes for the ethernet header

When comparing the result from len(pkt) with the extracted value from the IP header, they were almost always the same (ok, for very few packets there was a difference of 4-6 bytes but that's another question).

But once I implemented queues and threading into my code, the sizes from len(pkt) and the extracted value from the IP header are in most cases totally different. Sometimes there is a difference of just few bytes, and sometimes several hundred bytes. But very rarely they are the same.

The code in which I implemented threading is below. Does anybody have an idea if I made a mistake in the way I implemented threading/queues or what I am doing wrong?

```
import pcap
import struct
import dpkt
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def packet_handler():
    ts,pkt=q.get()
    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        return
    a=struct.unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s', pkt[14:34])
    print a[2]+14,len(pkt)

def start():  
    pc.loop(0,lambda ts,pkt: q.put((ts,pkt)))

q=Queue()
pc=pcap.pcap(name="eth0")
start_sniffer=Thread(target=start)
start_sniffer.start()

while True:
    packet_handler()
```

Part of the output looks like this:

```
419 1454
419 419
54 60
389 60
389 389
405 60
405 405
405 60
405 405
54 60
54 60
493 491
491 492
491 493
491 491
502 502
54 60
```

Comment: Is it possible that the lazy evaluation of the lambda is causing problems? See https://www.python.org/~jeremy/weblog/040204.html for more discussion

Comment: No, I tried also to make a separate callback function.

Comment: it probably as nothing to do with the problem, but why are you passing `q` to `start` when it can access `pc`? Both are globals.

Comment: You are right. I don't need to pass these variables. I will edit the post to avoid further confusion. Thanks! I also tested it again with the edited code, but the problem still remains...

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. Running the code you've posted produces the correct result (ie, `a[2]+14 == len(pkt)`). Can you copy+paste the output of running it?

Comment: I edited the post and added an example output.

Comment: Try to play a youtube video while sniffing. It happens that the values are the same if there is not much network traffic.

Comment: you are using queue and threading together, don't you have to use locks?  I have had  a code written using queues and threads but I was using Lock object.

Comment: I don't think I have to use locks because I have just one thread outside of the normal program flow. This thread is responsible for adding items to the queue, and the while loop is getting items from the queue. So I do not see any possibilities for collisions to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it. I changed this line:

```
pc.loop(0,lambda ts,pkt: q.put((str(ts),str(pkt))))
```

That means, I converted ts and pkt to strings before adding them to the queue.

Sizes for few packets are still different for 4-6 bytes, but that was also the case with the not-threading version. I will probably ask about that in a new post.

Thanks everybody for the help!!!